# how to start slideshow of pictures present in a folder in SDCARD

Tags: android, slideshow, android-intent

I have the Uri to the selected folder in SDcard(code working perfectly fine). All I want to do is to make a slideshow of pictures present in that folder. Kindly tell me the steps I have to follow. Any pointers would be greatly helpful.

Right now I'm able to display only a single picture using

```
BitmapFactory.decodeFile
```

and then passing that to image.setImagebitmap

Answer (score 0):

Try this code..it worked perfectly.

```
/** For Images Slidshow. */
     public int currentimageindex=0;
        Timer timer;
        TimerTask task;
        ImageView slidingimage;

        int[] IMAGE_IDS = {R.drawable.mic, R.drawable.mic5, R.drawable.mic6,
                R.drawable.mice7};

        //code of slideshow start from here

        final Handler mHandler = new Handler();

        // Create runnable for posting
        final Runnable mUpdateResults = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                AnimateandSlideShow();

            }
        };

        int delay = 1000; // delay for 1 sec.

        int period = 8000; // repeat every 4 sec.

        Timer timer = new Timer();

        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

        public void run() {

             mHandler.post(mUpdateResults);

        }

        }, delay, period);

    }


       private void AnimateandSlideShow() {

        slidingimage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView_id);
        slidingimage.setImageResource(IMAGE_IDS[currentimageindex%IMAGE_IDS.length]);

        currentimageindex++;

      }
//code of slideshow ends here
```